# Einstein's handwritten manuscript on General Relativity

Tags: physics, reference-request, einstein, physicists

The book "The Road to Relativity" by Gutfreund and Renn annotates Einstein's original handwritten manuscript from 1916 - "The Foundation of the General Theory of Relativity." I can find the original German published version as well as several translations but not the handwritten manuscript. Is there an electronic version available of the handwritten manuscript?

Comment: You mean [this facsimile](https://www.spbooks.com/en/95-la-theorie-de-la-relativite-generale-9791095457053.html)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's the one. I've been trying to find the images of that manuscript on-line.

Comment: It's proprietory, so there would be copyright issues with posting it online.

Comment: @Conifold: Under US law, it's in the public domain now, due to its age plus the fact that US law doesn't allow copyright on faithful reproductions.